# Moving returned data around from an ajax request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading some information from a page. I want to move some of the content around and then load it up to a div in the corrected order. Here's what I mean. Imagine this is the content on the page being called:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="product">some text 
    <div class="item" id="234"></div>

    <div class="description>More text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="product">some text 
    <div class="item" id="3343"></div>

    <div class="description">More text</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

These are just showing two products, but imagine it's 30 or so products. Now when I load the page using an ajax call, I want to re-arrange some of the content before I place it in a div. My new content should look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="product">some text 

    <div class="description>More text 
      <div class="item" id="234"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product">some text

    <div class="description">More text
      <div class="item" id="3343"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

So I took the "item" class and moved it into the description class. How do I accomplish this for all the products? It would look something like this I suppose:

```
$.get('/product-page',function(data){
  $('#container').html($(data).MOVE-STUFF-AROUND);
});
```

Comment: you'll need to write a function to `MOVE-STUFF-AROUND` I guess - you talk of moving "content" and show html being moved around, I take it `$.get('/product-page'` returns HTML?

Comment: If HTML is being returned, then move it around in the backend, not frontend. Why would you send the data in an order you don't want? You can send data according to user specification from the backend. Unless you're responsible for frontend, and have no say in in backend work?

Comment: @JaromandaX - You are correct. The product page returns html that i need to re-arrange to my needs.

Comment: @almostabeginner - You are correct. This is a 3rd party system and I have no control of the backend. Just trying to get the front-end to work the way i need it to. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure I got you right. You want to move a div labeled with a class "item" into another div (same level) labeled "description".

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from what is shown what you actually get as response. Assuming it is the full `wrapper` do:

```
$.get('/product-page',function(data){
    var $data = $(data);
    $data.find('.description').append(function() {
      return $(this).prev('.item');
    });
    $('#container').html($data);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3v4xf5eL/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Given this HTMl:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="product">some text     
    <div class="item" id="1111"></div>
    <div class="description">More text</div>    
  </div>                
  <div class="product">some text     
    <div class="item" id="2222"></div>
    <div class="description">More text</div>    
  </div>

</div>
```

Running this JQuery code:

```
 $(".product").each(function(i, obj) {
           let $prodcut =  $(this);
           let $item = $prodcut.children(".item");
           let $desc = $prodcut.children(".description");
           $item.appendTo($desc);
});
```

Will give you this output:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="product">some text             
      <div class="description">More text
        <div class="item" id="1111"></div>
     </div>   
    </div>          

  <div class="product">some text             
    <div class="description">More text
      <div class="item" id="2222"></div>
    </div>    
  </div>    

</div>
```

The way it works: I select all prodcuts divs. I loop into each one and select the div labled "`item`" and then I move that div and append it into a div labled "`description`". Both `item` and `description` are children of `product`.

DEMO:

```js
$(".product").each(function(i, obj) {
  let $prodcut = $(this);
  let $item = $prodcut.children(".item");
  let $desc = $prodcut.children(".description");
  $item.appendTo($desc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">


  <div class="product">some text
    <div class="item" id="1111"></div>
    <div class="description">More text</div>
  </div>


  <div class="product">some text
    <div class="item" id="2222"></div>
    <div class="description">More text</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume `/product-page` returns HTML since you suggest displaying it using `$('#container').html(data);`. If so, you can arrange your HTML in the backend script (product-page) so when you call it on AJAX, the HTML data is ready.

Or, you can opt `/product-page` to return JSON data, then arrange it in your JS code, e.g.:

```
$.get('/product-page', function(data) {
    $('.wrapper').html(''); // assuming you want to clear contents of .wrapper
    $.each(data, function (v) {
        var html = '<div class="product>"' + v.some_text;
        html += '<div class="description"'> + v.more_text;
        html += '<div class="item">' + v.item_details + '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        $('.wrapper').append(html);
    });
});
```

EDIT: 
Comments were already added before I could submit my answer, and realized above won't answer the OP, as AJAX endpoint comes from third party.

If the data comes from a third party, you need to create a DOM manipulator function based on your needs. Sadly, the construct depends on your needs.

Comment: Opps, sorry I just realized there were comments above already.

Comment: I have no control of what the html looks like on the loaded page. It's actually waaaaayyyyy more convoluted that what i put up as a sample. I just tried to simplify it as much as i could so i could present it to ya'll in a way that explains what i'm trying to do